# Relationship between similarity and having the same minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$, $B$ $\in M_3$ be nilpotent, where $M_3$ is the set of all complex 3by3 matrices. Show that $A$ and $B$ are similar if and only if $A$ and $B$ have the same minimal polynomial. Is this true in $M_4$?

One direction is clear. However, I don't see how having the same minimal polynomial implies similarity for nilpotent matrices. Also, why is the size of the matrix important? Any solutions or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The only eigenvalue of a nilpotent matrix is $0$. So, our minimal polynomial will be of the form $p(x) = x^k$ for some $k$.

We note that a matrix will have minimal polynomial $p(x) = x^k$ if and only if (it is nilpotent and) its largest Jordan block is of size $k$.

Comment: My guess is that if the size of matrix is 3 then k is either 1,2,or 3. If it's 1 A and B are 0. If k is 2 or 3, it forces the Jordan matrix to be either a single 1 on the superdiagonal or two 1's on the superdiagonal. However, in the case of the size being 4, we can't determine a single form of the Jordan matrix for different cases, and that is why we can't be sure when the size is 4. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: I think you have it.  Can you come up with two $4 \times 4$ Jordan matrices with the same minimal polynomial?

Comment: I'm a bit unfamiliar with minimal polynomials yet. Is there a method of finding matrices with the same minimal polynomials?

Comment: Use my if and only if statement.  In general, the exponent of a factor in the minimal polynomial is the size of the largest associated Jordan block.